# How to add hostname display to VIM statusline in Linux?

Tags: linux, vim

I'd like to add the short hostname to the statusline in vim. I've looked around but short of installing the Powerline plugin, it doesn't seem posible. Below is my `.vimrc`. How can I add the`hostname` variable to it?

```
let hostname=system('hostname -s')
set laststatus=2
set statusline+=%F\ %P\ %c:%l
```

UPDATE: to remove the '^@' which appears after the hostname on the vim status line (I suspect is a newline charcter from the hostname call) I use this instead:

```
let hostname=system('echo -n $LOGNAME@$(/bin/hostname -s)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`statusline` can be modified to include variable names.

For example, I'm using the `statline` plugin, so my `statusline`is:

```
statusline=[%{StatlineBufCount()}:%n] %<%1*[%f]%*%2*%h%w%m%r%* %y[%{&ff}%{g:statline_encoding_separator}%{strlen(&fenc)?&fenc:g:statline_no_encoding_string}] %5*%{&paste?(g:statline_show_paste_string):''}%*%5*%{&list?(g:statline_show_list_string):''}%*%=%-14( L%l/%L:C%c%V %)%P %4*%{exists('g:sfe_availableScms')?SfeStatus():''}%* %3*%{exists('g:loaded_syntastic_plugin')?SyntasticStatuslineFlag():''}%*%3*%{StatlineTabWarning()}%*%3*%{StatlineTrailingSpaceWarning()}%*
```

All of which is concatenated by the plugin itself.

In your case, you can use:

```
let hostname=system('hostname -s')
set statusline+=%F\ %P\ %c:%l\ %{hostname}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried everything but the curly braces

Comment: Do you know how to change the time with which the statusline gets updated? It would e useful for things that won't change at all or change very rarely.

Answer (score 5):

`vim` has a `hostname()` function (see `:h hostname()`), so you can do

```
:set statusline=%{hostname()}
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the time with which the statusline gets updated? It would e useful for things that won't change at all or change very rarely.

Comment: This approach is more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

The default [status line](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'statusline') can be more or less emulated this way:

```
:set statusline=%f\ %h%w%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

where

```
%f - buffer name (path to a file, or something)
%h - help flag
%w - preview flag
%m - modified flag
%r - readonly flag
%= - separater between the left (buffer name) and the right (ruler) parts
%-14.(...%) - minimum field width == 14
%l - line
%c - column
%V - virtual column
%P - percentage
```

One way to add hostname would be to use [`hostname()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#hostname()) function:

```
:set statusline=%#CursorColumn#\ %{hostname()}\ %*\ %f\ %h%w%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

where

```
%#CursorColumn# - sets highlight group
%{...} - embeds arbitrary expression
%* - resets highlight group
```

You might want to run the following script to see the list of available groups and what they [look like](https://jordanelver.co.uk/blog/2015/05/27/working-with-vim-colorschemes/):

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim
```

Or you can simply enclose the hostname in brackets:

```
:set statusline=[%{hostname()}]\ %f\ %h%w%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

See my [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518439/29867) if you want to get closer to the way status line is drawn by default.